# How to make soft Gulab Jamuns?

Tags: frying, indian-cuisine, pastry, deep-frying

I use [Gulab Jamun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulab_jamun) mix of the Gits company. http://www.gitsfood.com/gulabjamun/

The problem is that even on low fire the balls get brown from out side, but don't get cooked "properly" within.
When I try to cook it for a longer time, they tend to be hard.

What can I add to the mixture so that it cooks "properly" within and remains soft too?
Sodium bicarbonate? or something else can work too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add baking powder to the mixture, if needed, as it will cause them to puff up and lighten when cooked. Adding a little cream may also help.

I have a Gulab Jamun recipe from "Dance of Spices" by Laxmi Hiremath, pg 412, which lists the following for the dough:

- 0.5 cup (120 mL) unbleached all-purpose flour
- 2 cups (around 470 mL) powdered nonfat dry milk
- 1 tsp (5 mL) baking powder
- 1 cup (236 mL) heavy whipping cream (probably listed as "double cream" where you live, see [question on cream types](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15854/which-kind-of-cream-do-i-use-for-creme-brulee/15855#15855))
- about 1 TBSP water (15 mL)

The dry ingredients are mixed, then the cream is gradually mixed in, and the water is added to make a smooth, pliable dough.

Comment: Thanks Bob, but 'pastry' here is referred to a small piece of cake. :) BTW, how much baking powder should be added to the 200gm mixture? What are these 'Gulab jamuns' called n English?

Comment: I believe "pastry" is used on this site in a broader sense, as a post on creme brulee received the same tag.  In this usage, it refers to the restaurant brigade system, where the pastry station is responsible for breads, desserts, and baked goods.  I can't say PRECISELY how much baking powder to add, but I think 1/2 tsp or so would be a good starting point.  Finally, there is no English equivalent of gulab jamun.  I'd say that the closest food we have are doughnut holes, and they're not very similar.

Comment: Also... if you're getting bad results from your mix, you might try doing it from scratch, and mixing less.  Using fresh cream may help retain a tender texture by inhibiting gluten formation.

Comment: I didn't understand, what should from scratch? That mix is ready made. I am not supposed to do anything there else than adding water and baking soda now.

Comment: "From scratch" means try making it without using a mix.  A good mix should not need any changes to work.  If it doesn't work right when you use a good recipe and no mix, then there is another problem.  In that case it could be that you're mixing it too long.

Comment: The reason for using this mix is that, making the mixture from scratch proves to be more expensive, time consuming and cluttery. :D  I try the baking soda first and then the cream.

Comment: @Anisha Kaul if using a mix is less expensive than doing it from scratch, you can be absolutely sure that they used low quality ingredients. Usually a prefabricated food is more expensive than its ingredients.

Comment: @rumtscho That mixture is in the form of a powder. So they must be using powdered milk for it.

Answer (score 3):

My brother just made some Gulab Jamuns and had the same problem...You have to knead the dough really with lot of pressure and make it ultra soft. Then fry the balls in thick bottom pan on a low flame. Pans that become hot quickly will make the balls dark and wil not get cooked inside..

Comment: I will take care this time, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2):

- Kneading dough is important. Make sure you don't knead very tight and roll it very tight.
- While frying heat oil to high and reduce to medium. Wait for few seconds and fry the jamun in medium or low heat.
- Add baking powder which helps to soft.
- Dont leave the fried jamun out for long after frying. Drop it in sugar syrup. Make sure it dips completely in the syrup.

Answer (score 0):

While kneading dough add some milk which has small amount of heat.